# Incandescent light bulb glow around filament

Tags: visible-light

Hello I took this picture of an festoon bulb. I noticed three areas glowing. The darkest area (1) I identified as reflections from a metal plate behind the bulb. The brightest area (3) is obviously the filament. But what is the middle area (2)? Could it be the gas around the filament that gets hot and emit light?

The photo is actually not the bulb itself. It is an image formed by a convex lens on a white screen. The bulb was too bright to photograph directly.

[image: Incandescent light bulb]

Here is lamp that holds the bulb:

[image: Lamp with bulb]

Thank you!

Comment: The separation of colors makes my vote for dispersion in a lens.  The convex lens or the glass of the bulb, or both.  Many lenses don’t handle the light very neatly, especially around the edges.

Comment: I think its coming from the bulb since I'm am able to focus the area into a narrower line if I move the screen forward a bit. That, of course, makes the filament out of focus.